Brownian bridge as a limit of SDEs
Let $B$ be a Brownian motion and with respect to some probability measure $\mathbf{P}$ and filtration $(\mathcal{F})_{t \geq 0}$ and let $S_\epsilon = \{B_1 \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\}$.
For every $t \in[0,1]$ introduce the probability measure $\mathbf{Q}_t^\epsilon$ on $\mathcal{F}_t$ as $\mathbf{Q}_t^\epsilon(\cdot) = \mathbf{P}(\cdot \mid S_\epsilon)$.
It is not hard to see that
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{Q}_t^\epsilon}{d\mathbf{P}} = \frac{\mathbf{P}(S_\epsilon \mid \mathcal{F}_t)}{\mathbf{P}(S_\epsilon)} = F_\epsilon(B_t,t)
$$
for
$$
F_\epsilon(x,t) = \frac{\int_{S_\epsilon} \frac1{\sqrt{1-t}} \exp(-(y-x)^2/2(1-t)) \,dy}{\int_{S_\epsilon} \exp(-y^2/2) \,dy}.
$$
One can now tilt the thing by the martingale $F_\epsilon(B_t,t)$ and use Girsanov theorem to conclude that $B$ satisfies an SDE
$$
dB_t = dW_t^\epsilon + G_\epsilon(B_t,t)\,dt \qquad  (*)
$$
for some $W^\epsilon$ a Brownian motion on $[0,1]$ with respect to $\mathbf{Q}_1^\epsilon$.
On the other hand, there is a well-known SDE for the Brownian bridge:
$$
dB_t = dW_t - \frac{B_t}{1-t}\,dt
$$
Is it possible to obtain this SDE by taking $\epsilon \to 0$ in (*)? What are the relevant results showing that taking such a limit is indeed permissable?
